# Django error when referencing model from views doublequote

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

```
ProgrammingError at /app-name/url-name
    relation "TableName" does not exist
    LINE 1: SELECT (1) AS "a" FROM "TableName" WHERE "TableName..."
```

I have done an `inspectdb`, confirmed the mapping matches what is automatically set when running `makemigrations`, and deleted all migrations from the django_migrations table and re-ran `migrate`. I also checked that the migrations are successfully imported, by looking at the django_migrations table,as well as running `showmigrations`.

I wonder why I see the double quotes around the table names, is that why new models cannot be used? Interestingly, if I reference the model to be used in a form (not a view) it does seem to work okay, I see the correct inputs in the form coming from the database. The error happens when I query using Django - this query is setup within the same model 'TableName' itself, is that referenced correctly? (instead of doing importing TableName from app-name.models)

```
TableName.objects.using('CUSTOMDBSETTING').filter(colid='value')
```

Note that this works when I try using the shell directly, just not through Django. I also don't have a primary key for this table, and when I try setting up a non-default (not id), it gives me another error.

So it does give me the error when I try to reference what should be the primary key (but isn't) in the table mapping. When I try removing the primary key for the specific id (only in models, not in the migrations)

> ('42S22', "[42S22] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL
>   Server]Invalid column name 'id'. (207) (SQLExecDirectW); [42S22]
>   [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Statement(s)
>   could not be prepared. (8180)")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the answer to this question is that if one doesn't assign a specific unique/primary key in the model in question, the default 'id' mapped in Django would apply.

That is, expect your migrations to have a primary key like this (the model mapping wouldn't explicitly show this):

```
fields=[
    ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
...
]
```

To fix this issue, either use the primary key 'id' from Django or setup a primary key - doesn't have to done for the actual table, just the Django model. Then re-run the migrations and make sure they applied to catch this change...
Now, migrations should look like this (and no 'id' key would be used)

```
 ('tableid', models.CharField(blank=True, db_column='TableID', max_length=255, primary_key=True, serialize=False)),
```

or something like this if it's auto incremented

```
customid = models.AutoField(db_column='CustomID', null=False, primary_key=True, max_length=10)
```